# Pad a selection of columns using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How could I use the pandas pad function (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pad.html)
to pad only selected columns in a dataframe ?
For example, in the below dataframe (df):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, np.nan, 0, 1],[np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan ],[np.nan,3,np.nan, 3]],columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)

     A    B    C    D
0  2.0  NaN  0.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0
```

I would like to **only pad column A and column D**  keep the rest of the columns as it is. The final dataframe should look like :

```
     A    B    C    D
0  2.0  NaN  0.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  5.0  1.0
2  2.0  3.0  NaN  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try column assignment and `pad`:

```
df[['A', 'D']] = df[['A', 'D']].pad()
```

---

```
>>> df
     A    B    C    D
0  2.0  NaN  0.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  5.0  1.0
2  2.0  3.0  NaN  3.0
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, so the pandas pad() function can in no way be used to be applied on a subset of columns ?

Comment: @PrateekDaniels What is the "pandas pad() function"?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pad.html